# Changing selected column in fixed-format file

Tags: shell

I have a following file (in fact it has much more columns and enormous amount of lines)

```
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   3-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
   0   0 -40 336.902  26.500   2-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
   0   0 -41  37.034  15.869   5-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
   0   0 -42  27.538  14.992   1-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
```

It is a fixed-format file. In the 6th column I have numbers (format: I4) which start from 1 and go to 5. In this particular column I would need to replace 1 to 20, 2->21 etc. leaving all other entries unaffected. In this example it would yield something like:

```
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981  22-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
   0   0 -40 336.902  26.500  21-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
   0   0 -41  37.034  15.869  25-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
   0   0 -42  27.538  14.992  20-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
```

I looked into the forum but none solution seems to be exactly my case. With many thanks in advance.

Here is an appendix for the question. This is the original single line (note the whitespaces):

```
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   3-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954  0 287.85 405.71    5.51 287.32 405.17    5.58 1.894 0.53  11.62  90.00 322.65 2 9561     2947   8902   1.67   1 1.000  536346150 -4 0.936   33.55  151.65  91.270 174.170   1
```

Last suggested solution gives:

```
0   0   -39 36.093  14.981  23-0.71520  0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954 0   287.85  405.71  5.51    287.32  405.17  5.58    1.894   0.53    11.62   90.00   322.65  2   9561    2947    8902    1.67    1   1.000   536346150   -4  0.936   33.55   151.65  91.270  174.170 1
```

Comment: Start by looking into awk.

Comment: can you give the Fortran format of the line?

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` will split the 6th column into two parts and the are represented by `a[1]` and `a[2]` . Later 6th column is assigned with updated value were `a[1]` is incremented by `20`.

```
awk '{split($6,a,"-");$6=a[1]+20"-"a[2]}1' inputfile
0 0 -39 36.093 14.981 23-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
0 0 -40 336.902 26.500 22-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
0 0 -41 37.034 15.869 25-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
0 0 -42 27.538 14.992 21-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
```

You may optionally used `OFS="\t"` to have cleaner output. OR use `gsub`:

```
   awk  '{split($6,a,"-"); gsub($6,a[1]+20"-"a[2])}1'  input
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   23-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
   0   0 -40 336.902  26.500   22-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
   0   0 -41  37.034  15.869   25-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
   0   0 -42  27.538  14.992   21-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
```

When input file is :

```
cat input
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   3-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
   0   0 -40 336.902  26.500   2-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
   0   0 -41  37.034  15.869   5-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
   0   0 -42  27.538  14.992   1-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   3-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954  0 287.85 405.71    5.51 287.32 405.17    5.58 1.894 0.53  11.62  90.00 322.65 2 9561     2947   8902   1.67   1 1.000  536346150 -4 0.936   33.55  151.65  91.270 174.170   1


awk  'NF{split($6,a,"-"); gsub($6,a[1]+20"-"a[2])}1'  input
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   23-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954
   0   0 -40 336.902  26.500   22-0.69704 0.69704-0.16844 0.16844-0.69696-0.69696
   0   0 -41  37.034  15.869   25-0.67794 0.67794-0.17335 0.17335-0.71439-0.71439
   0   0 -42  27.538  14.992   21-0.65776 0.65776-0.17833 0.17833-0.73181-0.73181
   0   0 -39  36.093  14.981   23-0.71520 0.71520-0.16345 0.16345-0.67954-0.67954  0 287.85 405.71    5.51 287.32 405.17    5.58 1.894 0.53  11.62  90.00 322.65 2 9561     2947   8902   1.67   1 1.000  536346150 -4 0.936   33.55  151.65  91.270 174.170   1
```

[image: vimdiff between input and output]

Comment: Thanks, but this does changes the format. You can see the columns are of different length after the operation. They must be still in the fixed format,

Comment: Do `awk  '{split($6,a,"-"); gsub($6,a[1]+20"-"a[2])}1'`

Comment: Thanks. Much better but some other lines changed format. First column has i4, but now it has no whitespaces.

Comment: can you show the lines which are wrongly modified ? as we need proper input to provide proper solution.

Comment: See appendix to the question. It was hard to paste it here.

Comment: Now with gsub it works almost perfect, but adds 1 extra whitespace:)

Comment: check the update, there is no extra space , number of space is same as of input file

Comment: In your example above you do get it. Format was i4 (14.981___3), now it is i5 (14.981___23). Or a misunderstanding. The numer of spaces must decrease, otherwise everything shifts to the right.

Comment: splitting on a minus sign makes no sense, the 7th column cold be positive

Comment: but I am splitting 6th column when FS is default. how can 7th column go positive ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have a fixed-format file with a particular output.
Your 6th column has format `I4` which is a Fortran format specifier.

Since we do not have the full format, I did the following:

1. Get the position of column 5

   ```
   $ awk '{match($0,$5); print RSTART+RLENGTH-1; exit}' file
   28
   ```

This implies that column 6 starts at position 29 and has a length of 4.
Based on this number we can now split each file into 3 parts. The first string of length 28, the second string of length 4 and the third string which is the remainder. We add 20 to the second part and print it in the same format:

```
$ awk '{p1=substr($0,1,28); p2=substr($0,29,4); p3=substr($0,33)}
       { printf "%s%4d%s\n", p1,p2+20,p3}' file
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you guys a lot.

Comment: @rk85 If this answered your question, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers